# Why firstEntry() is not the first entry of a map?

Tags: java, treemap

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<Integer,Integer>map=new TreeMap<>();
    map.put(1,2);
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e = map.higherEntry(0);
    System.out.println(e==map.firstEntry());
}
```

The entry of *e* and *map.firstEntry()* is both *(1,2)*, but they are not the same since the *System.out.println()* function will print *false*. I am really confused.

I want to get a *true*.

Comment: it works if you use equals() instead

Comment: In Java, the `==` operator tests for reference equality (i.e., are the two references pointing to the exact same object in memory). You likely don't want that, and instead want to test for logical equality. In that case, use the `Object#equals(Object)` method. But that assumes the class of whichever object `equals` was called on has overridden the method to give a sensible implementation (by default, the method behaves the same as `==`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you have to compare them by using `equals`
(`e.equals(map.firstEntry())`).

It is because it wraps the map entry in a new `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` for each of the two calls. Hence the two references of the `Map.Entry` (`e` and `map.firstEntry()` in your code) are different, but they are *equal*.

Here's the source code of `TreeMap`'s `higherEntry` and `firstEntry`.

```
public Map.Entry<K,V> higherEntry(K key) {
    return exportEntry(getHigherEntry(key));
}

public Map.Entry<K,V> firstEntry() {
    return exportEntry(getFirstEntry());
}
```

The `exportEntry` static method wraps the `TreeMap.Entry` in a new `SimpleImmutableEntry` object.

```
static <K,V> Map.Entry<K,V> exportEntry(TreeMap.Entry<K,V> e) {
    return (e == null) ? null :
        new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e);
}
```